# Clarification Regarding Solid Angle

Tags: geometry, physics, solid-angle

I am studying Zangwill's *Modern Electrodynamics* but I'm having trouble following an argument he makes about solid angles in preparation for deriving the integral form of Gauss's law.

He defines the solid angle $\Omega_{S}$ subtended by a surface $S$ at a point $O$ as

\begin{equation*}
\Omega_{S} = \int_{S}{\frac{\mathbf{r}_{S}}{\left|\mathbf{r}_{S}\right|^{3}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,\mathrm{d}S}
\end{equation*}

where $\mathbf{r}_{S}$ is the vector from $O$ to the area element $\mathrm{d}S$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ is the outwardly directed normal vector to $S$ at $\mathrm{d}S$.

He asks the reader to consider a closed surface $S$ that encloses a volume $V$ and puts two cases: one in which the point $O$ lies inside of $V$ and one in which the point $O$ lies outside of $V$. He provides the following figure.

[image: Zangwill, p.72]

Here is his subsequent explanation:

"The left side of [the figure] shows that every ray from $O$ intersects $S$ an even number of times if $O$ is outside of $V$. Adjacent intersections where the ray enters and exists $V$ make the same projection onto a unit sphere centered at $O$ but cancel one another in [the integral] because $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}_{S}$ changes sign. Conversely, if $O$ is inside of $V$ (right side of [the figure]), every ray makes an odd number of intersections and the set of intersections closest to $O$ project onto the complete unit sphere with surface area $4\pi$."

This argument relying on the parity of the number of intersections of certain rays doesn't make sense to me. I would be grateful for any pointers or clarification.

Comment: Do you agree that all the surfaces intersected by a generalised cone of vertex $O$ subtend the same solid angle?